# How to geocode US addresses using gisgraphy (400k)

Tags: openstreetmap, gisgraphy

Would someone please direct me in geocoding around 400k addresses using gisgraphy or openstreetmap?

Comment: This question is quite broad, if you ask a more specific question and outline the steps you have taken so far you will get a better answer.